# Confusing, why not able to call out void passenger and there is no any error

Tags: java

I am new learner to Java. Need some advise from expert. I want to make the program to ask how many passenger when every selected floor reached. I notice if I removed the call request the loop will just work for one time. But I need it to keep repeat and repeat. Anyways to make it happen without remove any current other methods? Thanks.

```java
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Elevator {
    private int currentFloor;
    private static final int MAXFLOOR = 15;
    int newFloor;
    int newP;
    int currentP = 1;
    int maxP = 20;

    public Elevator() {
        currentFloor = 1;
    }

    public void passenger() {
        Scanner scanner1 = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter total passenger: ");
        newP = scanner1.nextInt();
        if (newP > maxP || newP == currentP) {
            System.out.println("Invalid passenger number");
            passenger();
        }
        else {
            if (newP < currentP) {
                minPassenger();
            }
            else if (newP > currentP) {
                maxPassenger();

            }
        }
        passenger();
    }

    public void maxPassenger() {
        System.out.println("Maximum passenger");
    }

    public void minPassenger() {
        System.out.println("0 passenger, not acceptable");
    }

    public void display(Object a) {
        System.out.println(a);
    }

    public void request(Object a) {
        System.out.println(a);
    }

    public void delay(int ms) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(ms);
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
        }
    }

    public void moveUp() {
        System.out.println("Starting at floor " + currentFloor);
        while (currentFloor++ < newFloor) {
            System.out.println("Going up -  now at floor " + currentFloor);
            delay(600);
        }
        currentFloor--;
        System.out.println("Stopping at floor " + newFloor);
    }

    public void moveDown() {
        System.out.println("Starting at floor " + currentFloor);
        while (currentFloor-- > newFloor) {
            System.out.println("Going down -  now at floor " + currentFloor);
            delay(600);
        }
        currentFloor++;
        System.out.println("Stopping at floor " + newFloor);
    }

    public void request() {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter new floor: ");
        newFloor = scanner.nextInt();
        if (newFloor > MAXFLOOR || newFloor == currentFloor) {
            System.out.println("INCORRECT FLOOR NUMBER, NO ACTION TAKEN");
            request();
        }
        else {

            if (newFloor < currentFloor) {
                moveDown();
            }
            else if (newFloor > currentFloor) {
                moveUp();

            }
        }
        request();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Elevator e = new Elevator();
        e.request();
        e.passenger();
    }
}
```

Comment: Calling passenger, inside passenger, will lead to an infinite loop. This is called recursion. The same is true for your request method which is why your output shows a looping path asking for a new floor. Main never gets to passenger. I think you mean to call passengers inside request. It may be wise for you to consider reworking your question, images are not good form I believe.

Comment: Hi,  firstly please NEVER post images of code, but always just the actual text.  For example I wanted to find where “passenger” was being called from, but that prevented me from doing a normal find in my browser.   It’ll also stop people being able to copy/paste your example to reproduce the problem in their IDE.   For theoroblem, it seems you have “passenger()”  calling itself - and that’ll mean once called, it’ll call itself, then call itself again ... repeatedly and so never stop.

Comment: Ok, Sorry. Looks like my code is too long and system not allow me to post it in onetime. I separate it to two part Question/Answer column

Comment: Ok the previous answer was deleted

Comment: What do you mean by "not able to call" it? You said there is no error, so what specifically is the problem? Please edit the question to include full details of what you want to happen and what actually happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is your `main()` method.

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Elevator e = new Elevator();
    e.request();
    e.passenger();
}
```

Method `request()` **never** ends, because the last line in that method is a call to itself. Hence the line `e.passenger()` is never executed.

You should put a `while` loop in method `main()` and decide on a way to terminate the loop, for example entering a floor which is negative. And remove the last line in method `request()` – likewise with method `passenger()`, remove the last line where you call the method again.

I believe the following code does what you want. Note that you only need to create a `Scanner` object once.

```java
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Elevator {
    private Scanner scanner;
    private int currentFloor;
    private static final int MAXFLOOR = 15;
    int newFloor;
    int newP;
    int currentP = 1;
    int maxP = 20;

    public Elevator() {
        currentFloor = 1;
        scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    }

    public void passenger() {
        System.out.print("Enter total passenger: ");
        newP = scanner.nextInt();
        if (newP > maxP || newP == currentP) {
            System.out.println("Invalid passenger number");
            passenger();
        }
        else {
            if (newP < currentP) {
                minPassenger();
                passenger();
            }
            else if (newP > currentP) {
                maxPassenger();
            }
        }
    }

    public void maxPassenger() {
        System.out.println("Maximum passenger");
    }

    public void minPassenger() {
        System.out.println("0 passenger, not acceptable");
    }

    public void display(Object a) {
        System.out.println(a);
    }

    public void request(Object a) {
        System.out.println(a);
    }

    public void delay(int ms) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(ms);
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
        }
    }

    public void moveUp() {
        System.out.println("Starting at floor " + currentFloor);
        while (currentFloor++ < newFloor) {
            System.out.println("Going up -  now at floor " + currentFloor);
            delay(600);
        }
        currentFloor--;
        System.out.println("Stopping at floor " + newFloor);
    }

    public void moveDown() {
        System.out.println("Starting at floor " + currentFloor);
        while (currentFloor-- > newFloor) {
            System.out.println("Going down -  now at floor " + currentFloor);
            delay(600);
        }
        currentFloor++;
        System.out.println("Stopping at floor " + newFloor);
    }

    public void request() {
        System.out.print("Enter new floor: ");
        newFloor = scanner.nextInt();
        if (newFloor < 0) {
            currentFloor = newFloor;
            return;
        }
        if (newFloor > MAXFLOOR || newFloor == currentFloor) {
            System.out.println("INCORRECT FLOOR NUMBER, NO ACTION TAKEN");
            request();
        }
        else {
            if (newFloor < currentFloor) {
                moveDown();
            }
            else if (newFloor > currentFloor) {
                moveUp();
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Elevator e = new Elevator();
        while (e.currentFloor >= 0) {
            e.request();
            if (e.currentFloor >= 0) {
                e.passenger();
            }
        }
    }
}
```